# Highlight selected list item with selector in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock

He guys i want to highlight the selected list items in a list view. I use ActionBarSherlock and set a selector to the list. I think it is the same as [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/list_selector_holo_dark.xml). The selector i use comes with ABS.
I add a Checkbox to each row so i see which one is selected. But i want a visual feedback like in the Gmail App.
[image: Selected List Row are highlighted]

So my question is following:

It is possible to style a highlighted row with a Selector or it is required to set the row style programmatically?

Note: I build my app for Android 2+ and want to use the style from Android ICS like ActionBarSherlock it use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.

For the ICS list selector (shiny blue one) i set in my ListView at the start the ActionBarSherlock list selector.

For highglighted list rows which indicates a selected item i extends a RelativeLayout which is my root layout for ListRows and implement the Checkable interface. In this interface i set a new background drawable in the setChecked( boolean ) method.

Her a good examples:

Highlight technic: [1](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/CheckableFrameLayout.java)
ICS selector: [2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/res/drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_dark.xml)